# What's this move called in gymnastics?

Tags: gymnastics

This is what I've seen as stunts in movies.
I have no real visual examples but I might be able to explain in words?

- It's when you run forward then start to flip. First both hands on the floor, then continue the flip, both feet on the floor, continue the flip, both hands on the floor, etc.
- Hands on floor, feet on floor, hands on floor, feet on floor, and you continue to flip. Forward or backwards.
- It works best if executed fast I guess.
- Leeloo Minai Lekatariba-Lamina-Tchai Ekbat De Sebat for example was doing a variation of that move in "The 5th Element"

So what's the move called? Is there a list where I could browse through gymnastic moves?

**Edit:** Thanks to Sean I found what I was looking for: [YouTube-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHFPuBywhEg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a gymnastics movement in movies.

Comment: @rrirower This is not about movies. Movies would only serve as examples. Sadly I'm not doing gymnastics and I know no one who does. Here I want to educate myself a little about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the feet and hands wind up on the ground at the same time, that's a [front walkover](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Front-Walkover). It's been some years since I saw *The Fifth Element*, but it's more likely that she was doing a [front handspring](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEQQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikihow.com%2FDo-a-Front-Handspring&ei=gZsBVfmkOJKwyASmzIKICQ&usg=AFQjCNExxRF4JWUrqk_rGDNz8Y8So0BM4w&sig2=p9hxbjCJrSuFviY_aIOAOQ&bvm=bv.87920726,d.aWw), which involves pushing oneself up off the ground as the legs come down. The former is generally a demonstration of flexibility and control and the latter is considered a more dynamic movement that requires greater power. It also tends to be faster because of the extra push.

And there are any number of sites where you can browse gymnastics terms. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_gymnastics_terms), for one.

Comment: Handspring is the correct keyword.